# Sencha touch panel darkens

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am using Sencha touch with phonegap. Whenever I click (or touch) at the top of my main panel near the phone status bar the entire screen darkens until I release. I moved my background down some 20px and found that the screen darkens when I click on the actually panel itself. This only seems to happen in the iPhone simulator and not while I'm debugging in the browser. I'm not sure what is causing this but is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: same here :( any ideas anyone?

Comment: Can I see some code? Is it a simple panel and what is the config object used? Is this the root view element or is the panel item in some other view object?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1400315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparently a Sencha bug. See this forum thread: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?157903-Screen-flickers-when-clicked-on-the-side